# Print a C string in Python

Tags: python, c

I want to print a C string using the Python `print` statement. The array `vendorName` contains the ASCIIZ C string `A ANTHONY & SONS INC`. My motivation is to convert the C string to a Python string such that I can use all of the Python string methods.

I have a struct:

```
class _vendrRecord(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1                                            # pack the struct
    _fields_ = [
        ("vendorName"            ,c_ubyte *(40 + 1)),
        ("ytdPayments"           ,c_ulong),
        ]
```

I want to print the string "vendorName" which is ASCIIZ.

I can print it using printf like this:

```
printf(b"%s\n", vendrRecord.vendorName)
```

I have tried this `print(vendrRecord.vendorName)` but it just prints the address. Based on information from Jamie Nicholl-Shelley, I tried `print(cast(vendrRecord.vendorName,c_char_p).value)` but that gives `b'A ANTHONY & SONS INC'`. I want simply `A ANTHONY & SONS INC`

Note that `print(vendrRecord.ytdPayments)` prints correctly.

Comment: Can't you access the string with `vendrRecord.vendorName.content`? I'm not so much into ctypes though.

Comment: `vendrRecord.vendorName.content` gives `AttributeError: 'c_ubyte_Array_41' object has no attribute 'content'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've figured out most of it and are just confused about string encoding.  You've managed to get to a `bytes` object:

```
>>> v.vendorName
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_41 object at 0xb0994a04>
>>> cast(v.vendorName, c_char_p)
c_char_p(176882328)
>>> cast(v.vendorName, c_char_p).value
b'A ANTHONY & SONS INC'
```

The [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) object is what it sounds like, just a sequence of bytes -- it's only as a convenience for the user that it's shown in a stringlike way.  Unlike a string, each component is an integer:

```
>>> cast(v.vendorName, c_char_p).value[7]
78
```

But since we know that we're using ascii, we can *decode* this bytes object into a Python string, and then use all of the usual methods on it:

```
>>> s = cast(v.vendorName, c_char_p).value.decode("ascii")
>>> s
'A ANTHONY & SONS INC'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> s.lower()
'a anthony & sons inc'
```

Comment: Perfect! This does exactly what I want. It is interesting that your Python prints s.lower() with quotes but mine does not. I'm using the latest 32 bit version.

Comment: @Eddy: I didn't *print* anything.  Since I was working at the console, it showed me the *repr*.  If I'd done `print(s.lower())`, there would have been no quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the address as that is what you have asked the code to do.
You have told it that it is a string type, but not declared it as a string in the function, instead use a pointer to the data at the address

Compared to print(), which figures this out for you as it a c++ based function

Comment: That information got me closer but still not all the way. `print(cast(vendrRecord.vendorName,c_char_p))` gives `c_char_p(b'A ANTHONY & SONS INC')`. How do I dereference it such that it is now a Python string? So I tried `print(cast(vendrRecord.vendorName,c_char_p).value)` but that gives `b'A ANTHONY & SONS INC'` (note the `b`).

Comment: Sorry I don't do much Python now days.
I imagine it's an output type identifier that's used to link with the python compiler.